# Need rewrite rule with wildcard

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need a htaccess rewrite rule to rewrite:

```
https://example.com/accounts/{user}/info
```

to

```
https://example.com/accounts/info
```

The `{user}` will be a dynamic part where this directory is not available so it needs to be a wildcard part within the rule.

Since it will be a URL where query posts will be sent to I need to forward all query params.

Answer (score 0):

To *internally rewrite* the request (ie. the URL does not change in the browser's address bar), you can do something like the following in the `.htaccess` file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^accounts/[^/]+/info$ accounts/info [L]
```

The "wildcard" regex `[^/]+` matches 1 or more characters except the slash (so it doesn't eat into the next path segment). If `{user}` should match a specific pattern then the regex should be made more specific.

Any query string parameters that are on the original request are passed through to the target URL.

Comment: seams not working result -> 404 not found (but info file is in place)

Comment: Is your file actually called "info" - with no file extension? Do you have any other directives in your `.htaccess` file?

Comment: in the directory of the info file there is another Htaccess which removes the .php so normally the file is info.php

Comment: In that case you should be rewriting directly to `info.php`, not `info`. But that secondary `.htaccess` file should not "remove" this `.php` extension.

Comment: changed it but results remain the same

Comment: Please include the contents of these `.htaccess` files in your question, with a summary of your directory structure.

Comment: "in the directory of the info file there is another Htaccess" - Is that at `/accounts/{user}/.htaccess` or `/accounts/.htaccess`? I assumed you mean the later?

Comment: this htaccess is /accounts/.htaccess and has content: RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]

Comment: And there is nothing else in the `.htaccess` file in the document root? What happens when you request `/accounts/info.php` directly? (Incidentally, those mod_rewrite directives don't "remove the .php", they add it back with an internal rewrite.)